# Remove /page/#/ at end of all urls

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

The old site had an issue with multiple pages for each URL because they had a module showing all blog posts on every page of the site.  The new site no longer needs /page/#/

```
For example:
about/page/2/
about/page/3/
etc.
```

How do I remove the /page/#/ at the end of all URLs so that:

```
domain.com/about/page/#/
```

becomes

```
domain.com/about
```

This does not seem to work:

```
RewriteRule ^/page/([0-9]+)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I added more info and pasted in my failed code.  Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not work either.  The URL does not get changed so I still get a 404.

Comment: Try this rule as **topmost** rule : `RewriteRule ^about/page/(\d+)/?$ /$1 [L,R=301,NC]`

Comment: That does change the url but it is not correct.  domain.com/about/page/#/ is returning domain.com/#  but I need it to be domain.com/about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this redirect rule as your as **topmost** rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/page/\d+/?$ /$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: This works for /about/ pages, but the page/#/ is an issue on all pages.  That is why I am trying to only remove /page/#/

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you for showing me the ([\w-]+) and \d+/ code.